# Can I execute function on `mysqli_error` after `or`?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, but I want to change it:

```
$res_getinfo = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlgetinfo) or die(mysqli_error($conn)."<br/>".$sqlgetinfo);
```

Something like this:

```
$res_getinfo = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlgetinfo) or mySQLlog();
```

Where mySQLlog is:

```
function mySQLlog($) {
    $file = fopen("mysql_error_log.txt", "a");
    $message = 'test';
    fwrite($file, $message . "\n");
    fclose($file);
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: why not to terminate `mysqli_query();` by semicolon and then use new line for function calling. like `mysqli_query($conn, $sqlgetinfo); mySQLlog();` and pass query error in `mySQLlog(your error);`

Comment: @devpro I want to execute `mySQLlog` only if `mysqli_query` has problem.

Comment: than its more simple `if (!mysqli_query(your query)){ mySQLlog( your error );}`

Comment: you can execute mySQLlog if mysqli_query fails, just check its return value. "Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE." - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh So this syntax is legit `$res_getinfo = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlgetinfo) or mySQLlog();` ?

Comment: Why not try and see what happens? It should be fairly simple to simulate cases where the first version executes the `die` case

Comment: @NicoHaase: agreed with u

Comment: Its an shorter version. `or` is a control operand - http://php.net/manual/language.operators.errorcontrol.php and `die` is an function similar to `exit` http://php.net/manual/function.die.php. You could use any function instead of `die` after `or` But just try it as @NicoHaase wrote

Comment: After all I would say, your version should work and it is legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comments, if you want to run your query errors in a specific function/method, then you can check either [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) return success of failure:

**Example:**

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"Your Query")) // your query will be use here
{
    myfunction(mysqli_error($con));
}

// function which you want use
function myfunction($error){ // your function will be use here
   echo $error; // will print error or your function body
}
```

**SideNote**: this is just an example, you can modify this example according to your requirement.